# Opensearch cluster - OpenSearch Security not initialized

Tags: opensearch

I am trying to deploy a new Opensearch cluster using Podman.
The containers standup, but when checking the logs I can see the following:

```
Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)
```

When I try and query the health endpoint I receive:

```
OpenSearch Security not initialized.
```

When attempting to initialize the cluster with the following command:

```
"/usr/share/opensearch/plugins/opensearch-security/tools/securityadmin.sh" -cd "/usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch-security" -icl -key "/usr/share/opensearch/config/kirk-key.pem" -cert "/usr/share/opensearch/config/kirk.pem" -cacert "/usr/share/opensearch/config/root-ca.pem" -nhnv
```

I receive the following error:

```
Security Admin v7
Will connect to localhost:9200 ... done
Connected as "CN=kirk,OU=client,O=client,L=test,C=de"
OpenSearch Version: 2.8.0
Contacting opensearch cluster 'opensearch' and wait for YELLOW clusterstate ...
Cannot retrieve cluster state due to: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-2 [ACTIVE]. This is not an error, will keep on trying ...
  Root cause: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-2 [ACTIVE] (java.net.SocketTimeoutException/java.net.SocketTimeoutException)
   * Try running securityadmin.sh with -icl (but no -cl) and -nhnv (If that works you need to check your clustername as well as hostnames in your TLS certificates)
   * Make sure that your keystore or PEM certificate is a client certificate (not a node certificate) and configured properly in opensearch.yml
   * If this is not working, try running securityadmin.sh with --diagnose and see diagnose trace log file)
   * Add --accept-red-cluster to allow securityadmin to operate on a red cluster.
```

Using the `--diagnose` the following is reported:

```
endingClusterTasksRequest:
org.opensearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], host [https://localhost:9200], URI [/_cluster/pending_tasks], status line [HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_manager_not_discovered_exception","reason":null}],"type":"cluster_manager_not_discovered_exception","reason":null},"status":503}
    at org.opensearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:375)
    at org.opensearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:345)
    at org.opensearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:320)
    at org.opensearch.security.tools.SecurityAdmin.generateDiagnoseTrace(SecurityAdmin.java:1028)
    at org.opensearch.security.tools.SecurityAdmin.execute(SecurityAdmin.java:598)
    at org.opensearch.security.tools.SecurityAdmin.main(SecurityAdmin.java:162)

IndicesStatsRequest:
org.opensearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], host [https://localhost:9200], URI [/_stats], status line [HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];"}],"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];"},"status":503}
    at org.opensearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:375)
    at org.opensearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:345)
    at org.opensearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:320)
    at org.opensearch.security.tools.SecurityAdmin.generateDiagnoseTrace(SecurityAdmin.java:1036)
    at org.opensearch.security.tools.SecurityAdmin.execute(SecurityAdmin.java:598)
    at org.opensearch.security.tools.SecurityAdmin.main(SecurityAdmin.java:162)
```

The following settings are being passed to each container:

```
  -e "cluster.name=foo" \
  -e "node.name=node1" \
  -e "discovery.seed_hosts=node1,node2" \
  -e "network.bind_host: [_local_, _site_]" \
  -e "cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=node1,node2" \
  -e "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g" \
  \
  docker.io/opensearchproject/opensearch:latest
```

Each container can ping and telnet the other containers on port 9200 and 9300.

I am trying to configure the cluster with the default TLS settings using the certificates provided by Opensearch.